# How do I make a custom taxonomy for a CPT appear inbetween title and editor boxes?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, order

This may be a duplicate of this question - [Changing the priority of a custom taxonomy's metabox](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40701/changing-the-priority-of-a-custom-taxonomys-metabox) but I can't work out how to apply that answer. I'm unsure what my custom taxonomy div label would be and how to get it to apply to only a custom post type.

I have a custom taxonomy, created with register_taxonomy and I would like to make the taxonomy box appear inbetween the post title field and the editor field in the wp-admin add/edit post area, for a set custom post type. Usually you can change CPT order in the admin menus with a priority field, but I don't think there is one for taxonomies...

Thanks

Comment: You may be interested in: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/100487/21376

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching s_ha_dum's link and others for a while it seemed like the only way to position meta boxes in between the title and editor fields was to remove and readd the main editor [like this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/101013/20327), but this feels a bit hacky to me and receives a warning from another answerer about potential problems.

I was able to combine @s_ha_dum's method for creating a position for a new meta box, and [this code](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/set-contextpriority-of-meta_box-based-on-registered-taxonomy#post-1648307) which enabled me to create a new meta box that functions like a category taxonomy.

In case it helps anyone, here is the working code to make a custom taxonomy appear in-between the title and editor:

```
/***************************************************************
* Function create_ideas_type
* Register ideas type taxonomy 
***************************************************************/
add_action( 'init', 'create_ideas_type', 0 );

function create_ideas_type() {

$labels = array(
    'name' => __( 'Type'),
    'singular_name' => __( 'Type'),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Types' ),
    'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Types' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Types' ),
    'parent_item' => null,
    'parent_item_colon' => null,
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Type' ),
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Type' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Type' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Type Name' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate types with commas' ),
    'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove types' ),
    'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most used types' ),
);

register_taxonomy('ideas_type','ideas', array(
    'label' => __('Type'),
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => false,   
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'greenhouse/ideas-ambitions/type', 'with_front' => false),
    ));
}
/***************************************************************
* Functions add_before_editor and move_ideaspost_box
* Reorder the metabox to appear in between title and editor
***************************************************************/ 
// use the action to create a place for your meta box
add_action('edit_form_after_title','add_before_editor');

function add_before_editor($post) {
    global $post;
    do_meta_boxes('ideas', 'pre_editor', $post);
}

add_action('do_meta_boxes', 'move_ideaspost_box');

function move_ideaspost_box() {

    global $post;
    if( $post->post_type != 'ideas' )
        return;

    remove_meta_box( 'ideas_typediv', 'ideas', 'side' );
    $t_name = 'ideas_type';
    if ( !is_taxonomy_hierarchical($t_name) )
        add_meta_box('tagsdiv-' . $t_name, "Type", 'post_tags_meta_box', 'ideas', 'pre_editor', 'low', array( 'taxonomy' => $t_name ));
    else
        add_meta_box($t_name . 'div', "Type", 'post_categories_meta_box', 'ideas', 'pre_editor', 'low', array( 'taxonomy' => $t_name ));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case you can edit the following code to accomplish what you are looking for by assigning the custom taxonomy meta box to a custom context and then running `do_meta_boxes`

```
/**
 * insert meta boxes before main editor below title
 */
function wpse_140900_add_meta_boxes_after_title( $post ){

    // per the comment below filter by post type
    // http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/140900/how-do-i-make-a-custom-taxonomy-for-a-cpt-appear-inbetween-title-and-editor-boxe/140906#comment201984_140906
    if( $post->post_type != 'targeted-post-type' )
        return;

    // setup function vars
    global $wp_meta_boxes;
    $current_screen = get_current_screen();
    $registered_taxonomy = 'custom_taxonomy';

    // move meta box to after_title position
    $wp_meta_boxes[$current_screen->id]['after_title']['core'][ $registered_taxonomy . 'div'] = $wp_meta_boxes[$current_screen->id]['side']['core'][ $registered_taxonomy . 'div' ];

    // display registered meta boxes for after_title
    do_meta_boxes( get_current_screen(), 'after_title', $post );

    // remove meta box from displaying in the "default"
    unset( $wp_meta_boxes[$current_screen->id]['side']['core'][ $registered_taxonomy . 'div' ] );
}

// init meta boxes after title
add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', 'wpse_140900_add_meta_boxes_after_title' );
```

In this particular code snippet it will move your sidebar meta boxes below the title and above the content editor fields.

Comment: Thanks for this. I use a few custom meta boxes already though. How about if I just wanted that specific taxonomy meta box to be displayed there, and the rest in their usual order? I'm unsure how to target a specific one...

Comment: Oh and also, this changes the meta boxes for every single post type. How do I target just one?

Comment: I just updated the code sample to reflect your desire to filter by post type. Specifically for the custom meta boxes you already registered, did you create them via `add_meta_box` or are they just registered custom taxonomies?

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. They're just registered custom taxonomies. Is it easier to create them via add_meta_box in terms of setting priority? I would have done that, but I would like them to function as categories, not tags or standard meta input boxes.

Comment: I updated the function to include the migration and display of a registered taxonomy

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't get this to work in the end. But I used your `if( $post->post_type != 'targeted-post-type' )
        return;` code to target my post type. I had to add `global $post;` above to get it to work though.